# AngularJS - Ng-class choose wrong class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've a problem with my App, normally , ng-class displays a different background according to the time indicated in the database.

It works fine on other views ( Home, and when creating ), but in the ad page, it defaults to the class "night" .
I was fine all night searching , but I have not been able to find where the problem is , this is what I have in console:

```
<div class="item night" ng-class="{"sunset":true}"></div>
```

And in other view (When it's work) :

```
<div class="item sunset" ng-class="{"sunset":true}"></div>
```

I'll precise : All services in all views are the same.
Do you have an idea of ​​where it may come ?

HTML :

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="item" ng-class="{{ event.starthourid | setImageClass}}">
  <h2 class="text stable animated tada" id="eventtitle"> {{ event.nameid }} </h2> 
</div>
```

Service.JS :

```
myApp.filter("setImageClass", function(){
  return function(input) {
    var h = new Date(input).getHours();
    if (h>=6 && h<11) {
      return {sunrise: true};
    } else if (h>=11 && h<18) {
      return {day: true};
    } else if (h>=18 && h<22) {
      return {sunset: true};
    } else {
      return {night: true};
    }
  };
});
```

Thank you all for reading! (I can add code if you want)

Comment: Please add the related code too!

Comment: Avijit Gupta , it's done !

Comment: How does `starthourid` look like? Can you give a sample value?

Comment: This looks like this : "1970-01-01T19:00:19.000Z"

Comment: Does the values from the ad page that default to *night* look also like that?

Comment: If you are able to log the event.starthourid for the ad page, then it might give you some clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution : starthourid is not defined, so I passed starthourid in StateParams :

HTML :

```
<div class="card" ui-sref="tabevent({ eventid: event.$id, eventhour: event.starthourid })">
```

App.JS :

```
  .state('tabevent', {
    url: '/tabevent/:eventid/:eventhour',
    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-event.html',
    controller: 'EventCtrl',
  })
```

Controller.JS :

```
$scope.starthourid = $stateParams.eventhour
```

And the Detail Page :

```
ng-class="{{starthourid | setImageClass}}"
```

And now it's work !

Thanks all for your time, hope it's can help someone. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-class="{"sunset":true}"
```

should be

```
ng-class="{sunset: true}"
```

or

```
ng-class="{'sunset': true}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the curly braces `{{}}` around `ng-class` expression.

Following are valid expressions for `ng-class` attribute,

`<div ng-class="className">`

`<div ng-class="getClassNameFunc()">`

`<div ng-class="{className: booleanValue}">`

Below is a sample snippet.

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);

app.controller("testCntrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.isNight = false;
  $scope.checkNight = function() {
    $scope.isNight = !$scope.isNight;
  }

  $scope.getIsNight = function() {
    return $scope.isNight;
  }
})
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px
}
.night {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.day {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="testCntrl">
    <div id="div1" ng-class="{night: getIsNight()}">
      <span ng-show="!isNight">Its Day </span>
      <span ng-show="isNight">Its Night </span>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="checkNight()">{{isNight ? "Day": "Night" }}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand why my code work in home view and doesn't work in detail view ...
We have 4 class : Sunrise, Day, Sunset, Night. All class are defined by hour set by Ad creator (If 12 = Day, If 7am = Sunrise etc.), not defined onclick ... (Sorry for my bad english I'm french)